# Set HtmlEditorExtender as ReadOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I'm using the HtmlEditorExtender component from AjaxToolKit and I'm having some trouble.

I'm trying set the HtmlEditorExtender as ReadOnly but I can't find a way to do it.

Setting the TextBox associated with the HtmlEditorExtender as `ReadOnly = true` or `Enabled = false` is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlEditorExtender uses div with `contenteditable='true'` attribute, so the question can be rephrased as "How to make a contenteditable div read-only?"

There are some answers for that, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360530/make-a-contenteditable-div-read-only) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273377/div-contenteditable-but-readonly).